# Перебор списка и вывод разных текстов

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, for, перебор

Есть код:

```
import urllib3
    
filename = "links.json"

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

for url in content:
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    resp = http.request('GET', url)
    print(resp.status)

print("Всего проверенно" + str(len(content)))
```

Как мне сделать, что бы для каждого статуса выводился разный текст?

Что-то вроде:

Ссылка 1 имеет статус 404
Ссылка 2 имеет статус 200

и т.д...

Comment: print(f'Ссылка {url} имеет статус {resp.status}')

Comment: вам требуется разный текст для каждого статуса или просто текст для каждой ссылки с указанием ее статуса?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте счетчик для номера ссылки:

```
for i, url in enumerate(content, 1):
```

и выводите на печать состояние счетчика и статус:

```
print(f'Ссылка {i} имеет статус {resp.status}')
```

В вашем случае:

```py
import urllib3

filename = "links.json"

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

for i, url in enumerate(content, 1):
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    resp = http.request('GET', url)
    print(f'Ссылка {i} имеет статус {resp.status}') 

print(f'Всего проверенно: {len(content)}')
```

- [enumerate(iterable, start=0)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) принимает последовательность, по-умолчанию начитается с 0;
- [f - строка](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) - тоже хорошая штука, в фигурные скобки можно вписать любое выражение.